# Knockout Js: UI is not updating after deleting Item

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin

I am using the Knockout JS, I have a delete function which is working, but my UI is not updating with deletions, it displays the item which has been deleted, Even in my DB, the data has been deleted, How do I fix this?
code:

```
  function UserViewModel()
  {
    var self=this;
      self.UserProfile = ko.observableArray([]);

      //Get user all details
       self.GetUserDetails=function(){    
       $.ajax({
         type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        data: Model,
        url: serverUrl + 'api/controller/Action',
        success: function (data) {
      var UserDetailsmappedData = $.map(data, function (item) {
                    return new userModel(item);
                });
     self.UserProfile (self.UserProfile ().concat(UserDetailsmappedData));
        },
        })
        }

       //Delete Profile
      self.DeleteUserProfile = function (UserProfile)
      {

      var ProfilestatusID = (UserProfile.UserProfileID())
      console.log(ProfilestatusID)
      Model = { userID: ProfilestatusID }

      jQuery.support.cors = true;

      $.ajax({
         type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        data: Model,
        url: serverUrl + 'api/controller/Action',
        success: function (data) {
            self.GetUserDetails();
        }, 
         }) }

 //My Model
 function userModel(data){
    self.userId=ko.observable(data.userID);
    self.userName=ko.observable(data.userName);
    self.userImage=ko.observable(data.userImage)
  }

  $(document).ready(function () {
    viewModel=new UserViewModel();
    ko.applybindings(viewModel)
  });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The user profile you deleted never gets removed from the observablearray because the old array always gets merged with the updated one after the GetUserDetails() call.

Best thing would be if you just remove the user profile from the array in the success callback instead of calling GetUserDetails() again. So:

```
$.ajax({
     type: "POST",
    dataType: "json",
    data: Model,
    url: serverUrl + 'api/controller/Action',
    success: function (data) {
        self.UserProfile.remove(UserProfile); //DB is already updated, no
                                              //need to call 
                                              // GetUserDetails() again
    }, 
     }) }
```

Or if you want to keep the deleted items in your array for whatever reason, just update the UserProfile, eg:

```
UserProfile.deleted(true)
```

Comment: When i call self.GetUserDetails, I cant clear it and rebind once again  self.UserProfile

Comment: Sorry I don't quite understand your question. Just call GetUserDetails() once when your app starts and fill the UserProfile obervablearray like this: self.UserProfile(UserDetailsmappedData);

Comment: yes thanks, I asked in generally,once i have GetUserDetails(),so inside GetUserDetails() function, I cant use self.UserProfile.removeall() or self.UserProfile([]) like this before i hit at ajax clear all and bind again

Comment: Why wouldn't you be able to do that? You can always clear and fill an observable array as you like.

Comment: if i use self.UserProfile.removeall() or self.UserProfile([]) in  GetUserDetails() its wont get bind in ajax success,it will bind empty

Answer (score 0):

After delete you should remove the deleted items from the observable array `self.UserProfile`, here `self.UserProfile(self.UserProfile().concat(UserDetailsmappedData));` seems that you are concatenating the results to the existing array